# Entity Framework and asp.net MVC still throwing exception after copy and paste connection string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I can't figure why my mvc project is still throwing exception even after I copy and paste the connection string from the entity framework project

```
The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.


  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(local);initial catalog=theDatabase;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

any ideas?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: did you add <entityFramework> segment in you Web project config file?

Comment: I don't need it in the App.config why would I need such thing in the web.config?